# How to schedule Do Not Disturb settings in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, do-not-disturb

I'm trying to activate Do Not Disturb (DND) settings from my app. I can set the DND settings using this piece of code (Provided ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED is true):

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotificationManager.setNotificationPolicy(
                    new NotificationManager.Policy(NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_CATEGORY_CALLS | NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_CATEGORY_MESSAGES,
                            NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_SENDERS_CONTACTS,
                            NotificationManager.Policy.PRIORITY_SENDERS_CONTACTS));

mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY);
```

I used the Policy to prioritize only calls and messages from people in my contacts only, which works fine, they were set on the device DND settings too.

Now, I want to schedule this DND settings for a particular time period, like shown in the picture below:

[image: DND settings]

Can I schedule it programmatically and how?

Thanks.

Comment: @Ton Unfortunately, no. I was searching this when I worked for Samsung but never found the solution. Guess there is just not the API yet